# Android sax parser error while getting html data

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, saxparser

Hi Am trying to parse the data from xml which contains the html data using sax parser the data in xml is like below

but while parsing am getting the data between details tag as different strings, not getting as single string which contains full html data between dtails tag.

can anyone help me out please how can i resolve this.

```
<details>
    <html> <b>Animal Care BTEC Level 1</b>

        <hr style="height:0.03em;width:18em;border:1px ;border-style:dotted;margin-left:0; color:white"
        />

        <body>
            <e>Course Length: 1 year</e>
            <br />
            <e>Fees: Free for 16-18 year olds</e>
            <br />
            <e>Course Code: B332</e>
            <br />
            <br />

            <body> <b> Overview:</b>

                <hr style="height:0.03em;width:18em;border:1px ;border-style:dotted;margin-left:0 ;color:white"
                />
                <p>The course provides a basic introduction to working with animals. A practical
                    approach allows student to develop animal handling skills along side personal
                    and social development. Student will have access to a wide range of animals
                    to enable them to develop skills and confidence. Each week practical work
                    will include time spent on the animal unit, the farm and at the equine
                    centre to enable students to develop practical ability in all three areas.</p>
            </body>

    </html>
</details>
```

---

```
package com.bb.mypotential;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import android.util.Log;

public class SaxHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    public static Courseobj courseobj;
    public static Subject subjectobj;
    public boolean courseidb = false;
    public boolean coursesubjectb = false;
    public boolean coursetitleb = false;
    public boolean subjectidb = false;
    public boolean subjectnameb = false;
    public boolean subjectcodeb = false;
    public boolean subjectdetailsb = false;
    public boolean entryRequirementb = false;
    public boolean courseContentb = false;
    public boolean futhuroptionsb = false;
    public boolean additionalInfob = false;
    public boolean fundingInfob = false;
    public boolean assignmethodb = false;


public String currentvalue = null;
public ArrayList<Subject> subarr = null;

String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (localName.equals("Courses")) {
        MainListActivity.value = new ArrayList<Courseobj>();
    }
    if (localName.equals("Course")) {
        courseobj = new Courseobj();
        subarr = new ArrayList<Subject>();
        String courseid = attributes.getValue(0);// getValue("ID");
        courseobj.setCOURSE_ID(courseid);
        courseidb = true;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
        coursetitleb = true;

    } else if (localName.equals("subject")) {
        subjectobj = new Subject();
        String subid = attributes.getValue(0);
        subjectobj.setSUB_ID(subid);

        subjectidb = true;
    } else if (localName.equals("name")) {
        subjectnameb = true;

    } else if (localName.equals("code")) {
        subjectcodeb = true;
    } else if (localName.equals("details")) {
        subjectdetailsb = true;
    } else if (localName.equals("entryRequirement")) {
        entryRequirementb = true;
    } else if (localName.equals("courseContent")) {
        courseContentb = true;
    } else if (localName.equals("assignmentMethods")) {
        assignmethodb = true;
    } else if (localName.equals("furtherOptions")) {
        futhuroptionsb = true;
    } else if (localName.equals("additionalInformation")) {
        additionalInfob = true;
    } else if (localName.equals("fundingInformation")) {
        fundingInfob = true;
    }

}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    currentvalue = new String(ch, start, length);

    if (coursetitleb) {
        courseobj.setTitle(currentvalue);

    } else if (subjectnameb) {
        subjectobj.setName(currentvalue);


    } else if (subjectcodeb) {
        subjectobj.setCode(currentvalue);

    } else if (subjectdetailsb) {
        subjectobj.setDetails(currentvalue);

    } else if (entryRequirementb) {
        subjectobj.setEntryRequirement(currentvalue);
    } else if (courseContentb) {
        subjectobj.setCourseContent(currentvalue);
    } else if (assignmethodb) {
        subjectobj.setCourseContent(currentvalue);
    } else if (futhuroptionsb) {
        subjectobj.setFuthuroptions(currentvalue);
    } else if (additionalInfob) {
        subjectobj.setAdditionalInfo(currentvalue);
    } else if (fundingInfob) {
        subjectobj.setFundingInfo(currentvalue);
    }

}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Course")) {

        courseobj.setSubject(subarr);
        MainListActivity.value.add(courseobj);

        courseidb = false;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
        coursetitleb = false;
    } else if (localName.equals("subject")) {

        subarr.add(subjectobj);
        subjectidb = false;

    } else if (localName.equals("name")) {
        subjectnameb = false;

    } else if (localName.equals("code")) {
        subjectcodeb = false;
    } else if (localName.equals("details")) {
        subjectdetailsb = false;
    } else if (localName.equals("entryRequirement")) {
        entryRequirementb = false;
    } else if (localName.equals("courseContent")) {
        courseContentb = false;
    } else if (localName.equals("assignmentMethods")) {
        assignmethodb = false;
    } else if (localName.equals("furtherOptions")) {
        futhuroptionsb = false;
    } else if (localName.equals("additionalInformation")) {
        additionalInfob = false;
    } else if (localName.equals("fundingInformation")) {
        fundingInfob = false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I got resolved this by using string buffer , every time in handler  am appending the string to buffer and while retrieving am converting buffer to string..working fine now